# How do I build a wixproj from command line with the same parameters as through Visual Studio?

Tags: wix, wix4

I'm attempting to build an installer using WiX 4. I've installed Heatwave and Visual Studio 2022, created a WiX project and added my target solution as a reference. I was able to build in the IDE by right clicking on the WiX project and selecting build. However, I'm unable to get the same output by using the command line.

When I run through the IDE by right clicking and choosing "Build" or "Rebuild" this creates an installer in the **bin\x64\Release\en-US** folder, and the msi package has a platform of `x64` in the Summary Information stream.

However, if I try running:

```
dotnet build "MySetup" -c Release
```

where `MySetup` is the folder my wixproj is located in, the installer is created but is placed under the **bin\Release\en-US** folder (note that there is no reference of x64 in the path) and the resulting msi has a platform of `Intel` in the Summary Information stream. If I try running:

```
dotnet build "MySetup" -c Release -a x64
```

Then the build complains because my dependent project doesn't have a target for win-x64. Which seems to be beside the point, as Visual Studio was clearly able to build it.

How can I figure out what command line Visual Studio is using here? Apologies if this is obvious, I'm new to both WiX 4 and Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building in Visual Studio builds the .sln file and takes into account the Build Configuration found in the toolbar under Build > Configuration Manager. The .sln will set the platform specifically for each project, including whether to build x86, x64, or arm64.

Building with `dotnet build` will build the project in the directory you specify. You don't provide enough detail, but I'm guessing "MySetup" is a directory containing your .wixproj. So, you are directly building the .wixproj without the Build Configuration context from the .sln file. Thus, when you tell `dotnet build` to explicitly build x64, it does so for the .wixproj and all the projects it references.

I happened to hit exactly this sort of issue in [my last Deployment Dojo episode](https://youtube.com/live/-rvZi8QYa24). It isn't the episode's topic, but the Configuration Manager is used to fix the build and shows the more advanced configuration available in .wixprojs.

Comment: Without actually investigating, at first blush this does seem to be the issue! I'll take a look at this. I had started watching the Deployment Dojos recently but haven't gotten to the latest ones yet. I'll give that a watch!

Comment: So this did end up leading me down the right path. All my dependencies were managed code, so they were all using Any CPU while my msi projects were set to x64 (as they can't be set to Any CPU). Watching through the linked episode clued me into the fact that you can explicitly set platforms for your dependencies, so I set them to Any CPU, and passed in -p:Platform=x64 to my command line build. That gives me the behaviour I was expecting, and as a bonus, I also understand what it's doing now!

Comment: That's a pretty big bonus! :)

Answer (score 0):

In my build automation I use powershell to call

> dotnet build $slnFile -c Release /p:MSIProductVersion=$versionNumber -o
> $pwd\BuiltFiles\Installer\Release\

Comment: I tried this, assuming that $sInFile is my project, and this doesn't generate an msi package, just puts all the built files under the output folder. This confuses me, because if I literally don't supply an output, it creates the msi. This seems like an unintuitive result?

Comment: the -o output arg is like a default override / redirect. It's not required.  I use a .sln to contain my .wixproj  but you should be able to skip that.

Comment: My point is that if I don't include -o, I get a .msi package as a result. If I do include -o, I get a folder with the files I intend to install as the result. I would have expected to get an msi either way. Also, I have a .sln but was trying to build only using the wixproj, I will try using dotnet build and the solution (rather than the project) and see if that changes things.

Comment: reach out to me at chrpai@iswix.com and I'll give you a complimentary 1 hour mentoring session.